# Nested If Statement with Variables declared outside

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have this block of code which is throwing error : "The syntax is incorrect".

```
SET "VAR1=UP"
SET "VAR2=UP"

IF ("%VAR1%"=="UP")
(
  IF "(%VAR2%"=="UP")
  ( ECHO "VALUES MATCH")
 )
```

But this keeps throwing error as mentioned above. Is the comparison syntax ( %VAR1%"=="UP") incorrect or there is any issue with Variable declaration?

The function of the code will be: There will be four such If blocks, each will compare the four possible values of the two variables and throw specific display message .

Would really be obliged if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for the `IF` command.  Open up a cmd prompt and type `IF /?` to read the help file for the `IF` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF ("%VAR1%"=="UP")
```

The string IF `("%VAR1%"` will never equal the string `"UP")`, regardless of the value of `var1` - these parenthesis for part of the comparison, you can't group them as a "Boolean".

```
IF "%VAR1%"=="UP"
```

is the correct *comparison* syntax, **BUT**

```
(
```

Which starts the grouping of the statements to cascade if the comparison is evaluated as *true* absolutely **MUST** be on the same physical line as the `if`.

The same goes for `else` - the syntax `) else (` must appear just exactly so.

Comment: This has worked.Thanks a lot for your help.Much obliged.